# How can I restrict date format in JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, json, datetime, .net-core, json.net

I'm wanting to reject incoming JSON request bodies with dates to using UTC time format (to remove ambiguity due to time-zones) using JSON.Net. I've looked into the following options, with no current success:

- I've looked at the `JsonSerializerSettings`, and I don't appear to be able to find a combination of the options `DateFormatString`, `DateFormatHandling`, `DateParseHandling` & `DateTimeZoneHandling` that actively restrict such requests. I would be happy if there is a solution using these options that would reject incoming dates in the wrong format.
- I've also looked into creating a custom `JsonConverter` (either using `JsonConverter` or `DateTimeConverterBase`); however the `JsonToken` type of these is `Date` and the `reader.Value` is already a `DateTime` object so I'm not able to verify the provided string (or if there is a way I'm missing it).

I'm hoping someone knows how to validate a deserialization of a JSON date object before it is automatically converted to a `DateTime` object, and can help me out.

Comment: means you need to find a way that knows the format of date right?

Comment: UTC is not a format... Perhaps you are mistaking with ISO8601? Anyway, you can use Json Schema to verify json structure (including data types).

Comment: @ershoaib Yes, that is the intent.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry, that's my bad I was being sloppy with terms. Yes I was meaning dates in ISO8601 format, but that they are given explicitly in UTC time, e.g. `"2018-10-29T10:41:32Z"` would be accepted but "`018-10-29T10:41:32"` or `"018-10-29T10:41:32+03:00"` would be rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be a combination setting DateParseHandling to not convert the DateTime string and then a custom JsonConverter for DateTime

A very simple Datetime converter that is going to blowup if its not a UTC datetime could be

```
    public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString("u"));
        }

        public override DateTime ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DateTime existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            string s = (string)reader.Value;
            return DateTime.ParseExact(s,"u", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
```

then your deserialization code would look like:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter>()
            {
                new DateTimeConverter()
            }
        };

        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDate>(json, settings);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I've just tested this and using `"u"` as the format string doesn't work. In particular it throws an exception for a valid and an invalid date. However the structure itself seems valid, which is good.

Comment: I used this structure with the format string `@"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss\Z"` to get the desired result.

Comment: Sorry "u" is the format "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"  no T in the middle.